# How can I create an object of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Mail.MailServer class?

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, devops, dbmail

I am trying to create an object of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Mail.MailServer class in PowerShell. The reason I need to do this is because I am trying to setup DBMail on the fresh instance of SQL using PowerShell. I am successfully able to create the MailAccount with the default mail server. But I need to create my own.

Could anyone help me to point to any example or reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this SQLServerCentral.com article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Database+Mail/74429/):

```
# Step 1 - Set variables for mail options. 
  $sqlServer = 'YourServerName'
  $accountName = 'dbMailDefaultAcct'
  $accountDescription = 'Default dbMail Account'
  $originatingAddress = "$sqlServer@yourDomain.com"
  $replyToAddress = 'DO_NOT_REPLY@yourDomain.com'
  $smtpServer = 'smtpServer.yourDomain.com'
  $profileName = 'dbMailDefaultProfile'
  $profileDescription = 'Default dbMail profile'

# Step 2 - Load the SMO assembly and create the server object, connecting to the server.
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
  $server = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server' ($sqlServer)

# Step 3 - Configure the SQL Server to enable Database Mail.
  $server.Configuration.DatabaseMailEnabled.ConfigValue = 1
  $server.Configuration.Alter()

# Step 4 - Alter mail system parameters if desired, this is an optional step.
  $server.Mail.ConfigurationValues.Item('LoggingLevel').Value = 1
  $server.Mail.ConfigurationValues.Item('LoggingLevel').Alter()

# Step 5 - Create the mail account. 
# ArgumentList contains the mail service, account name, description, 
# display name and email address.
  $account = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Mail.MailAccount `
   -Argumentlist $server.Mail, $accountName, $accountDescription, $sqlServer, $originatingAddress 
  $account.ReplyToAddress = $replyToAddress 
  $account.Create()

# Step 6 - Set the mail server now that the account is created.
  $account.MailServers.Item($sqlServer).Rename($smtpServer)
  $account.Alter()

# Step 7 - Create a public default profile. 
# ArgumentList contains the mail service, profile name and description.
  $mailProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Mail.MailProfile ` 
   -ArgumentList $server.Mail, $profileName, $profileDescription
  $mailProfile.Create()

# Step 8 - Associate the account to the profile and set the profile to public
  $mailProfile.AddAccount($accountName, 0)
  $mailProfile.AddPrincipal('public', 1)
  $mailProfile.Alter()

# Step 9 - Configure the SQL Agent to use dbMail.
  $server.JobServer.AgentMailType = 'DatabaseMail'
  $server.JobServer.DatabaseMailProfile = $profileName
  $server.JobServer.Alter()
```

Note that I would not use `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO')`, but most people do.

Using SQL Server 2014 as an example, I prefer:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll';
```

Or:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91';
```

Both of those explicitly call for the SQL Server 2014 version of the assembly, and explicitly calling for the correct version is what you should generally do.  You get bit when the wrong version of the assembly gets loaded, and you'll understand.  The drawback is you have to change your code if you're working on SQL Server 2012, 2008, etc.

For a general answer to the question of "which assembly contains this namespace," you can see in the [remarks on the MSDN page for the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.mail.aspx) which assembly contains the code you're after.